# How to view the source code of Java classes in Eclipse without ctrl+click?

Tags: eclipse

How can I view the source code of an any Java class in Eclipse without using the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd> at the already declared class field in the new java project?

For example, if I only need to view the sources of `FileInputStream` class, I need to create new java project, create new class, declare new class field `FileInputStream fis;`, import `java.io.*` and only then I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd> at the field `FileInputStream`. Is there any shorter way to reach the same result without creating the new java project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (on macOS: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>; menu: *Navigation > Open Type...*) to search for all types that is in your classpath, check the details [here](https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-find-java-class-in-eclipse/)

Nice thing about it is that you can search with first letters of each word in uppercase, for example to find `FileInputStream`, you can use `FIS`. I love doing so =)